# How to save vertical space in eclipse by removing status bar, quick access and splitted view controls?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, statusbar, text-editor

Here my eclipse window. I want to save all these space in order to gain vertical visibility (for my text editor). And I am unable to find the way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot disable either status bar nor toolbar. There is kind of solution though:

You can open a file and drag its tab with file name outside of eclipse window so it is detached from the main eclipse window. Then you can maximize this window and look on the code in kind of full-screen mode.

[image: Detached Eclipse code window]